# SQL Transact Statements in MSSQL or MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a Transaction Table as follows: Tr_No is primary key

```
Tr_No  Tr_Date        Tr_Remarks                    Tr_Amt
1     2014-05-05    Cash Deposited                   1000
2     2014-05-06    Credit Card Withdrawal           -250
3     2014-05-07    ATM Withdrawal                   -450
4     2014-05-08    Cash Deposited                   1000
```

I need a table as follows:

```
Date              Remarks              Cash Deposited   Cash Withdrawal  Balance
2014-05-05     Cash Deposited            1000                             1000
2014-05-06     Credit Card Withdrawal                     -250             750
2014-05-07     ATM Withdrawal                             -450             300
2014-05-08     Cash Deposited            1000                             1300
```

I need to write a SQL Query in MySQL or MSSQL to get the above table. Please help me as I'm new to SQL.Using a Select Statement is prefereable in Stored Proceures

Comment: @TomTom Thanks for the valid info but if you could help me how to write this query it would be more helpful for me .....

Comment: No, it would not. This question will be closed because we are not a code writing service. Want other people to do your work (which includes learning and trying) - hire them. Start by reading the site rules and what questions are not welcome here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This should give you an idea.

```
CREATE TABLE #tt
  (
     Tr_No      INT,
     Tr_Date    DATE,
     Tr_Remarks VARCHAR(100),
     Tr_Amt     INT
  )

INSERT INTO #tt
VALUES      (1,'2014-05-05','Cash Deposited',1000),
            (2,'2014-05-06','Credit Card Withdrawal',-250),
            (3,'2014-05-07','ATM Withdrawal',-450),
            (4,'2014-05-08','Cash Deposited',1000);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                CASE WHEN Tr_Amt > 0 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Tr_Amt) ELSE '' END    [Cash Deposited],
                CASE WHEN Tr_Amt < 0 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Tr_Amt) ELSE '' END    [Cash Withdrawal],
                Tr_Amt Balance
         FROM   #tt)
SELECT Tr_Date,
       Tr_Remarks,
       [Cash Deposited],
       [Cash Withdrawal],
       (SELECT Sum(Balance) Balance
        FROM   cte a
        WHERE  a.Tr_Date <= b.Tr_Date) AS Balance
FROM   cte b
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Tr_Date     Tr_Remarks              Cash Deposited  Cash Withdrawal Balance
----------  --------------          --------------  --------------- -------
2014-05-05  Cash Deposited          1000                            1000
2014-05-06  Credit Card Withdrawal                  -250            750
2014-05-07  ATM Withdrawal                          -450            300
2014-05-08  Cash Deposited          1000                            1300
```

Comment: Someone's homework has just been done for them.  Nothing learnt.